# creating a simple multiple choice quiz program or a test

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a simple quiz program with 30 questions (15 multiple choice) and have the order of all questions randomized. It also must calculate the result as a percent and display the questions answered wrongly with the correct answer. Even just a sample with 3 or 4 example questions would be fine.

I don't want the same question appearing more than once. Is there any free source code I can download so that I learn how to do this nicely. I am just a newbie and I really want to learn and see the tactics used.

I managed to do this, it is reading the questions from a text file but I would like to modify it to display the username and the scores of previous users, I would appreciate a modification to my program or if anyone with a source code for the simple quiz program I will appreciate.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,Unit2, StdCtrls, Grids;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
namefile, tmp : string;
f: text;
l,i,j,c: integer;
cc: double;
mas: array [1..100] of integer;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  reset(f);
  readln(f,l);
  for I := 1 to l do
  begin
    Form2.Label1.Caption := 'Вопрос № '+Inttostr(i+1);
     readln(f,tmp);
     Form2.Label2.Caption := tmp;
     readln(f,tmp);
     Form2.RadioButton1.Caption := tmp;
     readln(f,tmp);
     Form2.RadioButton2.Caption :=tmp;
     readln(f,tmp);
     Form2.RadioButton3.Caption :=tmp;
     readln(f,tmp);
     Form2.RadioButton4.Caption :=tmp;
     readln(f,j);

     Form2.ShowModal;

     if (Form2.RadioButton1.Checked) then
           if (j=1) then
              mas[i]:=1;
     if (Form2.RadioButton2.Checked) then
           if (j=2) then
              mas[i]:=1;
     if (Form2.RadioButton3.Checked) then
           if (j=3) then
              mas[i]:=1;
     if (Form2.RadioButton4.Checked) then
           if (j=4) then
              mas[i]:=1;
  end;
  c:=0;
  for I := 1 to l do
    if mas[i]=1 then
      c:=c+1;
  cc:=(c*100)/l;

  label3.Caption:= 'Правильных ответов '+FloatToStr(cc)+'%';

  for I := 0 to l-1 do
     stringgrid1.Cells[i,1]:=IntToStr(mas[i+1]);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  namefile:='test.txt';
  AssignFile(f, namefile);
  reset(f);
  readln(f,l);
  stringgrid1.ColCount:=l;
  for I := 1 to l do
    mas[i]:=0;
  for I := 0 to l-1 do
     stringgrid1.Cells[i,0]:=IntToStr(i+1);
  for I := 0 to l-1 do
    stringgrid1.Cells[i,1]:=IntToStr(mas[i+1]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Please try something and if you run into problems, you can always ask specific questions. If you have never programmed any serious Delphi program before, consider reading a book or a tutorial.

Comment: @anakata: Since this is the 20,547th Delphi question on StackOverflow, you must be new here.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe i understand but do you know where i can get source code for the same program

Comment: @user2353538: We're not providing the code. Your teacher assigned this homework so you will learn from it, and I suspect what you're supposed to learn is not "how to copy and paste other people's work and pretend it's mine".

Comment: @KenWhite honestly speaking this is not even home i just started learning delphi and this example is interesting i did it in c sharp and php aswell but how im doing it in delphi like the above example is horrible thats why i want to learn n not copy n paste

Comment: Voted for close as not a real question: it is too broad. You're literally asking for complete code, and that's not what this site is for. Maybe this [vote guide](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?p=204450#post204450) could serve inspiration.

Comment: Lol he went on Yahoo answers and posted same thing : http://malaysia.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130507123820AAB1XvC

Comment: @Nortd yes i did whats,wrong with u if u dont want to answer or give me ideas u think u r the only ones who can help,think twice besides someone emailed me the source...hahahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To partially answer:
If you want to maintain user scores your best bet to make progress on this level is to make a second text file for maintaining user names and scores.
Read them into an array. Ask the user name at program start, run the quiz, see if you already know him, update the array, write it back.

Your next step would be to learn database access and store all data in a database instead of text files.

That should give you enough exercise for now ;-)

Like Toon said, please ask specific questions here: I want this, tried this (here's the code), this fails, how to solve?

Also, once you have a working program, you may want to put it up on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to ask for improvements.
StackOverflow is not the place for that.